# Select certain rows if specific value comes 2 times within a date

Tags: sql

Basically I am creating an Attendance register for my school. I want to select certain rows if an specific value comes 2 or more times in a given period of times/date. My sql table looks like this:

[image]

I want an sql query so that I can select the yellow shaded rows because the `sid` comes 2 or more times in between the dates e.g. `4 April` to `6 April` (Here `att_date` is `date` and `att_month` is `month`)

Please help

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: not answering because not specific to sql version

Comment: @Aurelian I am sorry but I have no idea :/ I am using php framework by the way. Is that you are asking?

Comment: php would assume MySql but we cannot be sure

Comment: Why don't you store a date as a DATE?

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik I am using MySQL 5.6.17

Comment: @dnoeth storing the date would not solve the issue, perhaps, because  It may make the db quite large.

Comment: @ImranOmer Then add the `MySQL` tag to your question!!!  It helps people help you.  The last thing you want is people help you find a solution, but you can't use it because it's for different dbms.

Comment: A `DATE`
 needs more space than year/month/day as seperate columns?  3 bytes vs. 2+1+1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tblName
where DATE(att_date) in (4,5,6)
and MONTH(att_month) = 4 
GROUP BY sid
HAVING (Count(sid)>2)
```

Comment: and how for within a date, e.g. 4 april to 6 april

Answer (score 1):

**- Please try following if you want to fetch all the columns:**

select * from tbl t where
exists (select sid from tbl t1 where t.sid=t1.sid group by sid having count(*)>1)

**- Or try following if you just want to know the sid with multiple rows:**

select sid from tbl t group by sid having count(*)>1

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hope so this helps out.You should be more clear in your day,month and year logic.

```
CREATE TABLE tblname
    (`sid` int, `att_date` int, `att_month` int, `att_year` int)
;

INSERT INTO tblname
    (`sid`, `att_date`, `att_month`, `att_year`)
VALUES
    (31, 4, 4, 2018),
    (32, 4, 4, 2018),
    (2, 4, 4, 2018),
    (36, 4, 4, 2018),
    (37, 4, 4, 2018),
    (38, 4, 4, 2018),
    (38, 5, 4, 2018),
    (36, 5, 4, 2018),
    (2, 5, 4, 2018),
    (9, 5, 4, 2018),
    (2, 6, 4, 2018)
;

select * from tblname where sid in
(select sid
from tblname 
where att_date in(4,5,6)
and att_month=4
group by sid
having count(1)>=2)
```

Also check at-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01c696/16

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help is much appreciated.